# ubuntu 16.04 won't shutdown : Reached target Shutdown[ok] also ubuntu 14.04 won't shut down : killing all procces [fail]

Tags: 14.04, boot, 16.04, shutdown, reboot

I had ubuntu 14.04 (DELL laptop INSPIRON N-4110 )
shutdown and reboot worked correctly and without any problem
but after a long time I wasn't able to reboot or shutdown my machine.

and that was the log message was shown by pressing Esc during shutdown:

`killing all procceses  [fail]`

and I tried all the tips I saw in askubuntu and others(like changing the grub and `shutdown - h now` etc none of them have worked ! )

then I clean installed ubuntu 16.04 (current)
but issue is not going to solve.

now the log shows:

`[ok] Reached target Shutdown 
[135.486156] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0X0 action 0x6 frozen
[135.846776] ata2.00: cmd a0/00: 00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/s0 tag 4 pio 16392 in
[135.846776] get event status notification 4a  01 00 10 00 00 00 00 00res 40/00:00:00:00
[135.848020] ata2.00:status: { DRDY }
[141.182090] ata2.00 revalidation failed  (errno=-5)`

I checked bug #1464917 and did instructions also but nothings changed .

UPDATE:

after updating to 16.04.1 (boot install) Ubuntu will shutdown if i do it fast when OS is coming up but after a while it's not going to power off again and 
Esc key won't work and does not show me log any more

UPDATE(PROBLEM SOLVED) :
It was a certain hardware problem and solved by changing Hard Disc

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the swap is still active when reaching "Target shutdown";
My solution was to force swap deactivation before reboot :

> ```
>  swapoff -a
>  swapoff /dev/md6
> ```

after that, the reboot went fine for me without any pause.

Comment: I have exactly the same annoying problem. Where do you put these two lines?